# Building Mobile Routes on a Rails Server api

Tags: facebook, mobile, devise, omniauth, rails-api

I have been building out a server api for mobile developers to use for an iphone app. I have no experience with mobile development and they have no experience with ruby on rails. I have attempted to build a mobile authentication route for the app that allows users to log in via facebook.  So far, it looks like this:

GET '/auth/mobile/fbtoken=:facebook_token&device_id=:device_id&time_zone=:time_zone&os_type=:os_type', to: 'sessions#fb_sso'

```
  client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'],
  ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'],
  site: 'https://graph.facebook.com')
  token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, params[:access_token])
  user_info = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(token.get('/me').body)
```

The resources online for learning how to do this properly are very limited or nonexistant.  The only information I have found on how to do this involves using Devise for authentication.  Our app currently is equipped for Devise (it's been added and the migration has been made to the User model) but does not currently authenticate via Devise. One of the only specific examples that I have been able to find for what we're trying to do can be found at the bottom of the page on this post:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4409930

It led me to believe that I was on the right track with the way the route was set up, because everything is the same besides the last step "sign in using Devise method: sign_in @user, :event => :authentication."  This is what motivated me to attempt to integrate Devise into our application.

After reading that, what I meant to do was implement Devise in a sort of limited state and use only the sign_in method. Unfortunately, Devise seems to be very opinionated and more of an "all or nothing" sort of solution.  I'm very unsure of how to proceed and how to decide whether to completely rebuild a significant portion of our application to support Devise or to abandon it altogether and try to implement my own solution.

**tl;dr
1) Is it worth re-doing a significant portion of the Rails app to use Devise?
2) Is it possible to make this route work without Devise? How?**

Comment: Does the iOS app only need to support authentication through your rails app using facebook?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to have your users sign in through Facebook then Devise would be unnecessary as you would just be using Facebook's API with Koala or Omniauth to authenticate the user.  On the other hand, I see no reason why you couldn't have both your own authentication and Facebook authentication by also using Devise if you want non-Facebook users to use your app; you would just need either form of authentication to create a session.

And if I understand correctly, the solution at the bottom of your link doesn't use Devise for Facebook authentication but it's used to create a session when a person's FB account has been authenticated.  Seems like a reasonable way to go.

To answer your TL/DR:

1) Only if you plan on having both a Facebook login and a traditional login at the same time.
2) Yes.  Just give those GET parameters to a gem like Omniauth or Koala and create a session once the user has been authenticated.